# Store a integer javascript

Tags: javascript, html, math

Hi for instance if i have a integer that starts at `20` and then when i click button one it adds `10` to that 20 and then button 2 adds `4` ontop of the current count how would i do this ?

Comment: Fyi, _Javascript (ECMAScript) is a loosely typed language. That does not mean that it has no data types just that the value of a variable or a Javascript object property does not need to have a particular type of value assigned to it, or that it should always hold the same type of value. Javascript also freely type-converts values into a type suitable for (or required by) the context of their use._ [source](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/notes/type-conversion/)

Comment: Javascript doesn’t have integers, either.

Comment: Correct, all numbers in JavaScript are IEEE-754 double precision floating-points.

Answer (score 1):

have a global variable start with a value of 20, and then attach a function to the button click event for the two buttons, one of them adds 10 to the variable, the other adds 4 to the variable.  You might want to consider trying a problem and having some semi working code to show that you actually made an effort, otherwise chances are you are just going to get downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. **Notice that it follows best practices and doesn't leak any variables into the global scope.**

```
<button id="one" value="10">Add Ten</button>
<button id="two" value="4">Add Four</button>

<script>

    (function() {
        var myNumber = 20;

        var addValue = function() {
            myNumber+= +this.value;
        };

        var bindAdders = function() {
            var arr = [].splice.call(arguments);
            for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
                document.getElementById(arr[i]).onclick = addValue;
            }
        };

        bindAdders('one', 'two');
    })();

</script>
```

Comment: Be sure to `parseInt(this.value)` so it just doesn't concatenate it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentCount = 20;
</script>
<button id="button1" onclick="currentCount+=10;">Increase with 10</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="currentCount+=4;">Increase with 4</button>
<button id="show_currentCount" onclick="alert(currentCount);">Show count</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onload="updateCounter()">
  <span id="counter">x</span>
  <button onclick="javascript:x+=10;updateCounter();return false;">+10</button>
  <button onclick="javascript:x+=4;updateCounter();return false;">+4</button>

  <script>
    window.x = 20;
    window.updateCounter = function() {
      document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = String(x);
    };
  </script>
</body>
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9HbgU/).

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
<html>
<script>
    var someValue=0;

    function addValue(parm){
        someValue += parm;
        currentValueLabel.innerText = someValue;
    }
</script>
<body onload="addValue(20);">
    <input type="button" value="Add 2" onclick="addValue(2);" />
    <input type="button" value="Add 4" onclick="addValue(4);"/>
    <span id="currentValueLabel"></span>
</body>
</html>
```